# Find and replace every second occurrence of a word in a column macro

Tags: excel, vba

I want to change every second occurrence of a word in a column to a different word
example:

```
Column A    Column B      
Blank        123
Blank        124
XXXXX        125
Blank        126
Blank        127
XXXX         128
XXXX         129
XXXX         130
etc
Blank        150
Blank        151
```

I want to change every second 'Blank' to something else e.g. 'Blank1'
The number of rows varies up to ~ 300.
There may be up to about 30 occurrences of the 2 'Blank' pairs.
The XXXX are other labels
Want end result to be:

```
Column A    Column B      
    Blank        123
    Blank1        124
    XXXXX        125
    Blank        126
    Blank1        127
    XXXX         128
    XXXX         129
    XXXX         130
    etc
    Blank        150
    Blank1        151`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub Blanks()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") '<-- Update Sheet Name

Dim i As Long, lr As Long

lr = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To lr
    If ws.Range("A" & i) = "Blank" And (ws.Range("A" & i) = ws.Range("A" & i + 1)) Then
        ws.Range("A" & i + 1) = ws.Range("A" & i + 1) & 1
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```